# hibernate SaveOrUpdate : how to use

Tags: java, hibernate

Like to know how to use `SaveOrUpdate`, wish to insert the data and update the data again when specific column information is same.

I have created `Abrstract` class, The abstract(AbstractDao) class is extended in Dao and used in service class.

> When i used `beginTransaction` and `commit` while `SaveOrUpdate` i get error
>   " nested transactions not supported"

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    at com.my.myProj.mdao.AbstractDao.SaveOrUpdate(AbstractDao.java:26)
    at com.my.myProj.mdao.UniqueDataDaoImpl.saveOrUpdateUniqueData(UniqueDataDaoImpl.java:25)
    at com.my.myProj.service.UniqueDataServiceImpl.saveOrUpdateUniqueData(UniqueDataServiceImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.saveOrUpdateUniqueData(Unknown Source)
    at com.my.myProj.mainapp.savedb.StoreIdentityDataPacketDB.saveIdentityData(StoreDataDB.java:126)

    at com.my.myProj.mainapp.MainApp.run(MainApp.java:359)
```

I copied those `AppConfig` and `HibernateConfiguration` from net. I am not sure whether transaction is enabled in configuration. I would like to know the following

- How to use `SaveOrUpdate` : insert when new and update when already in table
- tips to lean / understand java configuration for hibernate configuration and app class configuration

Thanks!

```
public abstract class AbstractDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void persist(Object entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }

    public void delete(Object entity) {
        getSession().delete(entity);
    }

    public void SaveOrUpdate(Object entity) {
        Transaction tx3 = getSession().beginTransaction();
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
        tx3.commit();
    }
}
```

The hibernate config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.my.testProj.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.my.testProj.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

Dao Implementation

```
@Repository("UniqueDataDao")
public class UniqueDataDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements UniqueDataDao {    

    @Override
    public void saveUniqueData(UniqueData UniqData) {           
        persist(UniqData);    
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdateUniqueData(UniqueData UniqData) {           
        SaveOrUpdate(UniqData);    
    }    

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public  List<UniqueData> SelectUniqueTable(String sNum,String sSerNum) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Query query = getSession().createQuery("from UniqueData where S_NUMBER = :sModNum and S_SERIAL_NO = :sSerialNum");
        query.setParameter("sModNum", sNum);
        query.setParameter("sSerialNum", sSerNum);
        return query.list();
    }   

}
```

Service Implementation

```
@Service("UniqueService")
@Transactional
public class UniqueDataServiceImpl  implements UniqueDataService {

    @Autowired
    private UniqueDataDao UniqueDao;

    @Override
    public void saveUniqueData(UniqueData UniqData) {       
        UniqueDao.saveUniqueData(UniqData);    
    }

    @Override
    public List<UniqueData> SelectUniqueTable(String sNum, String sSerNum) {        
        return UniqueDao.SelectUniqueTable(sNum, sSerNum);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UniqueData> SelectUniqueTable(String sImeiNum) {        
        return UniqueDao.SelectUniqueTable(sImeiNum);
    }    

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdateUniqueData(UniqueData UniqData) {           
        UniqueDao.saveOrUpdateUniqueData(UniqData);
    }
  }
```

Main class code snippet : Its a command line application.

```
AbstractApplicationContext appContext = new   
                        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);    
UniqueDataService serviceUniq = 
                        (UniqueDataService) appContext.getBean("UniqueService");

          UniqueDataTable UniqDataTable = oPacket.getUniqDataTable();
          String sNumer = UniqDataTable.getsNumber();                

          UniqueData UniqData = new UniqueData();
          UniqData.setsNumber(sNumer);
          UniqData.setsSerialNum(sSerialNum);

          // save or update : insert or update
          serviceUniq.saveOrUpdateUniqueData(UniqData);
```

AppConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.testProj")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Comment: dur : i updated the question. does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

`saveOrUpdate` method insert the object if the id of the given object doesn't exist in database, if it does, the record in data base will take the same values from the object's attributs.

to make it easier for you you can imagine that it has the same instructions here :

```
    public Object saveOrUpdate(Object myObject) {

        if (myObject.getId().existsInDataBase()) {

            executeQuery("update Object set column1="+myObject.getAttribute1+" where id="+myObject.getId);
return myObject;

        } else {

            executeQuery("insert into Object(id,attribute1) values("+myObject.getId+","+myObject.getAttribute1+")");
return myObject;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Agree, but what about SaveOrUpdate method provided by hibernate? when i use this i get " nested transaction not supported"

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: you have this exception with your Transaction or Session Objects, do you have the same problem with the `save()` method ??